# Deployment in Weblogic 10.3, how to change properties

Tags: java, spring, deployment, weblogic

I have a spring application packed in war file. If i deploy in tomcat, i can go to file directory and find properties and xml files, and i can make changes, for example the name of the JNDI conexion, i restart the server, and everything is ok with new value. But now i have to deploy my app in weblogic 10.3, i can deploy and it runs, but if i want to change some properties of one properties file, i have to make a new war file and deploy again.

So my question is, how can i find this files without making a new war file? What is the best option to save this properties than can be changed in the future?

I want to make only one deployment, and after this, if changes properties are needed, any user can make this changes as easily as possible, for example changing a value of properties file.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for Weblogic deployment plans.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/config.html#wp1065363 for details.